GDAL Axis Order access via Python
(Heavily edited second try)
I'm using GDAL via a Python script to index rasters and gather properties / metadata. Some rasters use axis order 1,2 and some use 2,1. I have rasters that use the same axis mapping order (2,1) as obtained through the following code:
from osgeo import gdal
raster = gdal.Open(r"C:\Temp\sample.tif")
spatial_ref = raster.GetSpatialRef()
axis_mapping = spatial_ref.GetDataAxisToSRSAxisMapping()
print(f"Data Axis to SRS Axis Mapping: {axis_mapping}")

However, when I extract the coordinates from the geotransform and use rs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER) to force all to the same order, some of these are placed correctly and some have the X and Y transposed so they are placed incorrectly.
I can't figure out how to ensure that the coordinates I extract are in the right order. When the rasters are loaded into ArcGIS Pro or QGIS (or indexed via gdaltindex) their footprints are in the right place, so somehow the software / commands know where to put the footprint.
This is the relevant part of my code:
geo_transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
if geo_transform:
    x_min = geo_transform[0]
    y_max = geo_transform[3]
    x_max = x_min + geo_transform[1] * raster.RasterXSize
    y_min = y_max + geo_transform[5] * raster.RasterYSize
        
    target_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    target_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    target_srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source_srs, target_srs)

    ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    ring.AddPoint(x_min, y_min)
    ring.AddPoint(x_min, y_max)
    ring.AddPoint(x_max, y_max)
    ring.AddPoint(x_max, y_min)
    ring.AddPoint(x_min, y_min)
        
    footprint = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
    footprint.AddGeometry(ring)
    footprint.Transform(transform)

    footprint_wkt_string = footprint.ExportToWkt()
        
    footprint_geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(footprint_wkt_string)

Is the order linked to the spatial reference or to the raster itself? In other words, could the rasters be produced by some strange process where the spatial reference is recognized correctly even though the order is reversed?

https://gdal.org/en/stable/api/python/spatial_ref_api.html#osgeo.osr.SpatialReference.GetAxisMappingStrategy

Could you add a simple example about Python code that makes trouble? Why not to use osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER always? It would do nothing for the easting-northings and turn northing-eastings also into easting-northings.

@user30184 Yes, I should post the relevant code and gdalinfo from sample rasters. GetAxisMappingStrategy that user2856 posted is fine, but it gets the strategy from the srs and not from the raster - I think in my case the rasters themselves are wonky but I cannot help that, we get what we get from the users...

Coordinate system usually does not affect the raster data. GeoTIFFs are similar north-up images in EPSG:4326 and in UTM zones. Some format like NetCDF can be an exception.

@user30184 I heavily edited my original post to add some code snippets based on your first reply. I hope it explains the situation a bit more clearly.

I believe that your approach is too complicated. In the GDAL raster data model https://gdal.org/en/stable/user/raster_data_model.html#affine-geotransform the coordinates x and y of the top left corner are in order easting-northing or longitude-latitude. Also that is the order of coordinates that GDAL is using in WKT. The Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1,3 does not affect the geotransform. It means that in a normal north-up GeoTIFF image in EPSG:4326 the first data axis - pixels from left to right as they appear in TIFF - are increasing the second CRS axis - longitude.

I only included the line 'target_srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)' because otherwise the vast majority of the footprints were in the wrong place with x and y transposed. Now I'm trying to solve for the small but significant number of footprints that are still in the wrong place. Aside from sharing samples of the rasters (which I cannot do), is there any information that could help? Or maybe this is a wild goose chase and I'd be better to try to incorporate gdaltindex in my script instead...
